# Tensorflow tf.cond encountering error: TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'function'> to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Below is a minimal test case in which I create a variable `v` which I want to initialize to a value of 777 (for the simplified test case).

Note: I can't initialize `v` with a normal initializer because it depends on a normalization constant computed across all variables (some of which aren't yet created at the time `v` is created).

My solution (below) is to create a boolean variable `full_init_cond` that I set to True once I've run some initialization/assign OPs once and use `tf.cond` to ensure they only run the one time.

```
import tensorflow as tf

v = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
full_init_cond = tf.Variable(False, trainable=False, dtype=tf.bool)

with tf.control_dependencies([v]):
  tf.cond(
    full_init_cond,
    true_fn=lambda: [tf.no_op],
    false_fn=lambda: [tf.assign(v, 777), tf.assign(full_init_cond, True)]
  )
```

I'm receiving the following error on the `tf.cond` line:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'function'> to Tensor. Contents: <function no_op at 0x7f39abf51400>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

I'm not making much sense of this error.

---

Update:

To my surprise this simple test seems to produce a valid tensor:

```
tf.cond(full_init_cond, tf.no_op, tf.no_op)
```

Thought this one fails:

```
tf.cond(full_init_cond, lambda: tf.no_op, lambda: tf.no_op)
```

My confusion continues...
Tensorflow version 1.5 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambda: tf.no_op` doesn't work because you are passing a function that returns a function.

`tf.group` is needed so that the structures match between a list and a no_op return.

Below snippet runs in tf 1.11

```
import tensorflow as tf

v = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
full_init_cond = tf.Variable(False, trainable=False, dtype=tf.bool)

with tf.control_dependencies([v]):
  tf.cond(
    full_init_cond,
    true_fn=tf.no_op,
    false_fn=lambda: tf.group([tf.assign(v, 777), tf.assign(full_init_cond, True)])
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it didn't like the `tf.no_op` statement.

`tf.cond` requires that you return the same number and type of operations for either true|false conditions. So instead of `tf.no_op` I've replaced it with the `tf.identity` operation as an appropriate stand-in for no_op:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
full_init_cond = tf.Variable(False, trainable=False, dtype=tf.bool)

with tf.control_dependencies([v]):
  x = tf.cond(
    full_init_cond,
    true_fn=lambda: [tf.identity(v), tf.identity(full_init_cond)],
    false_fn=lambda: [tf.assign(v, 777), tf.assign(full_init_cond, True)]
  )

print(x)
```